# Is there a way to see which of your edits have been accepted

Tags: support, suggested-edits, activity

I want to know how valuable my edits are and want to know how many of them are accepted or rejected.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to your profile, change to the activity tab, and then change to the suggestions filter. This will list out all the suggested edits you've ever made. You can click on the "suggested edit" link in front of each one to see what happened to it (approved or rejected) and all the rejection reasons, if any.

Answer (score 1):

Visit any of your suggested edits and expand the section at the top.

For example, from [your most recent suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2151955), your current stats are:

> ajon had 6 edit suggestions approved, and 0 edit suggestions rejected